# React and express communication with HTTPS enabled

Tags: reactjs, express, https

I'm trying to finalize an HTTPS connection for a production server I'm building but am running into issues with HTTPS.

I've tried a few guides on how to set it up individually for both react and node but cannot seem to get the connection completed.

Here's a simplified version of my server.js file for express:

```
const https = require('https');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const server = express();
server.use(helmet);

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, server)
  .listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

And my frontend build path in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true && react-scripts start"
}
```

But when I go to `https://localhost:3000` I get the following from the console and the screen is only white

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE index.js:1437 
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your time and for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Where is the variable `port` coming from? You can try to read the certs by specifying the encoding like: `fs.readFileSync('server.key', 'utf8');`

Comment: @MattOestreich I'm using linux. Sorry its coming from a command line argument or defaulting to port 3030 for the backend (allowing for production builds to specify 80). In my case its 3030. Would a misread on the certs block the full render of the page? I'll give it a shot and see how it goes. Thanks for the response and info

Comment: Looks like you are using the Windows command to start as SSL - [try using this command](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development#linux-macos-bash) .. Furthermore, I would leave the `npm start` script alone/as default and create a new `npm` script, something like `"start:ssl": "HTTPS=true npm start"` .. Then from command line you can run `npm run start:ssl`

Comment: @ScottF any luck?

Comment: @MattOestreich Sorry for the delay in getting back to you- thank you so much for the help. It appears it resolved some issues when connecting with the backend but the frontend still doesn't recognize https